# How do I add a file formatter?

Tags: views, 7, files

I have used the accepted answer on [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72445/how-to-link-the-file-icon-to-the-file-and-to-hide-the-filename/72452#72452?newreg=57bdae1fc8df42ed8022d5eaae0f3367) to create and enable a custom module, but the new formatter doesn't appear in the list when I edit the file field in my view.

My info file looks like this:

```
name = Link icons
description = Turn file icons into links for use in views.
package = Views
core = 7.x
files[] = mymodule_link_icon.module
dependencies[] = views
dependencies[] = file

; Information added by MPM on 2015-07-30
version = "7.x-1.1"
core = "7.x"
project = "mymodule_link_icon"
datestamp = "1438243200"
```

Have I missed something in my info file or do I also need to amend something in the File module?

Comment: Everything looks just fine , check your code again maybe you have implemented hook_field_formatter_info in a wrong way

Comment: Other than removing blank lines it was a straight copy/paste (adding the opening php tag at the beginning) - I'll edit my question to include the module code.

Comment: And therein lies my problem, I didn't read the name of my own module! Thank you Alireza.