# Add a link to Large Filetype Icon

Tags: 7, files, media

I'm using the media module for displaying files.  I have PDF Preview set up, which falls back to the image formatter, and then Large Filetype Icon.  PDF Preview and the Image formatter are set up to link to the file, but Large Filetype Icon doesn't have that option.  How could I either alter that view to add the link or add a new formatter that does the same seem as the Large Filetype Icon, but with a link?

[image]

Comment: nobody knows anything about this?

Comment: This question has been already been answered here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72445/how-to-link-the-file-icon-to-the-file-and-to-hide-the-filename