# Drupal 7 - Custom File links

Tags: 7, theming, files

On my Drupal site, there's a specific type of content with a right panel (Documents), in which I add files (Field Type - file, Widget - file).

For **that particular type of content**, I wanted to change the way those files are displayed. Someone asked for help in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72445/how-to-link-the-file-icon-to-the-file-and-to-hide-the-filename), but I'm now quite sure it is the right way to go, since the solution mentions Views (I'm not using a View here) and **Linkable Icon** (never seen this option before).

I understand I might have to insert custom php code, but I'm not sure where. Is this a **theme** issue or **module** issue?